# Pytorch Lambda Transforms and pickling?

Tags: python, pytorch, pickle

I am beginning to read and experiment with Pytorch recently and I saw that the transform module has a `Lambda` class. currently as far as I am aware composing transforms requires just a callable and a plain lambda can suffice.

What's the purpose of the `Lambda` class if python lambdas work just the same? or I am missing something?

Comment: You are correct. In PyTorch, you can use a regular Python lambda function as a transform. However, the Lambda class in the torchvision.transforms module provides additional functionality that a regular lambda function does not. Here are some relevant sources for further reading [1](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Lambda) [2](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html) [3](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html#creating-custom-transforms) [4](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-use-lambda-transform/30646)

Comment: @Ayb009, 2/4 of the link you gave don't work and only the first references the word lambda once. 
What was I supposed to read?

Comment: The `Lambda` class in PyTorch's transform module and lambda function directly are almost the same and let users to create a transform using a lambda function. But it has some extra benefit of being able to pass the lambda function as an argument to functions that expect a transform object.

For example, the `Compose` function in the transform module expects a list of transform objects. Using the Lambda-class will let you pass a lambda function as a transform object.

Comment: @Phoenix That's where I started from actually. the `Compose` class. It accepts lambda as is. even in the constructor it just asks for "transforms" without indicating typing. It works with any callable (look at the implementation).
Where is the Lambda class different or more useful?